# What is the impact of prolonged electromagnetic exposure on human health?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology

What are the health effects of being exposed to a very strong electromagnetic field caused by  two resonating superconductive coils (not static magnets) for a period of years?

Comment: Your question would be a good fit for [skeptics.SE][http://skeptics.stackexchange.com]. There, you can provide a claim and they will tell you if there is some scientific support for this claim. And there are already many questions asked on the subject. If you can't find your answer, I'd suggest you to re-ask your question on skeptics.SE

Answer (score 1):

Actually the applications of magnetism to organic systems is new to Science.  Duke Univ in NC is currently experimenting with humans sticking their heads into large electromagnetic coils while electrodes are attached to the outside of the skull. A small amount of research has been done with magnetism and plant physiology (my interest), but in the main very little published research is available on the topic.  I might direct you to use Scholar.Google to find more technical articles rather than just using Google itself.